# How to assign to a nested map

Tags: dictionary, go

I have something like

```
type rateLimit struct {
    Count    int
}
```

```
type RateLimiter struct {
    cachePeriod   time.Duration
    rateLimits map[string]*rateLimit
}
```

And a function like this:

```
func NewRateLimiter(////) *RateLimiter {
    rateLimits := make(map[string]*rateLimit)

    return &RateLimiter{
        cachePeriod:   cachePeriod,
        rateLimits: rateLimits,
    }
}
```

This structure allows for you to create a nested structure like
`rateLimits["foo"] = a`

but I'm trying to make changes so that it is nested and I can do `rateLimits["foo"]["bar"] = a`

I tried changing the structure to be
`rateLimits := make(map[string]map[string]*rateLimit)`

and

```
type rateLimiter struct {
    cachePeriod   time.Duration
    rateLimits map[string]map[string]*rateLimit
}
```

but I'm getting `panic: assignment to entry in nil map [recovered] panic: assignment to entry in nil map`

Comment: "assignment to entry in nil map" means what it says: you tried to assign a value to a key in a map, but the map is `nil`. You need to initialize the map before you can use it.

Comment:   thank you!! The issue was with the way I was initializing the map, not with my actual structs.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
rateLimits := make(map[string]map[string]*rateLimit)
rateLimits["foo"] = make(map[string]*rateLimit)
rateLimits["foo"]["bar"] = a
```

```golang
rateLimits := map[string]map[string]*rateLimit{"foo": {"bar": a}}
```

Comment: This was the solution! Thanks for posting, I'm still learning my way around go and pointers :)

Answer (score 1):

You must make the nested map:

```
func setNested(m1 map[string]map[string]string, k1, k2 string, v string) {
    m2 := m1[k1] 
    if m2 == nil {
       m2 = make(map[string]string)
       m1[k1] = m2
    }
    m2[k2] = v
}
```

Use it like this:

```
 setNested(rateLimits, "foo", "bar", a)
```